# How to get the Cart insert id and updated cart id magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am doing a magento customization site , am new to magento anyboby pls help to get the addtocart insert id and cart updated Id .what coding should i apply in controller

```
app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php
```

or where should i found the cart insert operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the cart ID, after adding a product to cart, run the following statement:

```
<?php
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$cart_id = $cart->getQuote()->getId();
echo $cart_id;
?>
```

I did not test it. But hope it works.

Comment: it didn't works, I have added the code in app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php ,addAction() below  $cart->save();

Comment: i get the quote_id but i need the item_id of sales_flat_quote_item table how can i get that one?

Comment: you can get it by using direct queries. look here..


 http://nahidacm.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/direct-sql-queries-in-magento/

Comment: i need  cart insert id and cart updated Id i need to update the sales_flat_quote_item using that id

Comment: thank you for your help  i got id . i user product id and quote id to get the item_id from sales_flat_quote_item table.